# AngularJS: create a regex for first two character of a string alphabet and rest should be numeric

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Never really used AngularJS and am having issues figuring out how to create a regex for an input to check/allow only first 2 characters to be letters & the rest numbers.

Hope this makes sense.

Using pugJS

```
.e-field
    label.e-field__label(for='invoiceNr') Invoice Number
    input#invoiceNumberInput.e-input(
      ng-model='$ctrl.invoiceNumber'
      name="invoiceNumber"
      ng-required="true"
```

invoiceNr example: `HN123123123`

The ng-pattern was the answer. This is what I used:

`ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6,}$/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex for first 2 character is number and rest is digits in angularJS input is as below. Use `ng-pattern` and the specified RegEX

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]*$/"
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I don't know why I didn't come by this 'ng-pattern' in my searches... it worked well :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the integration into Angular. However as a RegEx I think you could use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]+$
```

(See test [here](https://regex101.com/r/9Cyw7x/3))

...Just a quick comment regarding the use of `..[0-9]+$` as opposed to `...[0-9]*$`

I think you should use + and not *. Otherwise a string like "HN" will also validate but I understood you only want to validate if it has numbers after the letters (like "HN1" or "HN123"..). For this case you should use "+".

Comment: Thanks! It was the integration part I was having the issue with :) 

"ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]*$/"" from above worked, in case you're interested in the implementation

Comment: Hi @iNano! Thanks! I just added to my answer regarding the use of + versus * - I also updated the linked example. I think in your case you want to use +$ at the end of the RegEx and not *$ . That way it requires to have at least one number following the letters. Cheers! :)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Good information to have regarding the */ +